# what is the correct way to cancel multiple tasks in c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library, task, pfx

I have a button thats spawns 4 tasks. The same button changes to a cancel button and clicking this should cancel all 4 tasks. Should I pass the same cancel token to all 4 tasks and have them poll on the same token for IsCancelRequested ? I am confused after reading the msdn doc on [createlinkedtokensource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642265.aspx). How is this normally done ? thank you

Update: Task.WaitAll() waits tills **all tasks complete execution**. Similarly how to know when **all tasks have been canceled** once the shared cancel token source is set to cancel.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect your update.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yeah, what you said about using a single `CancellationToken` is correct.  You can create a single `CancellationTokenSource` and use its `CancellationToken` for all of the tasks.  Your tasks should check the token regularly for cancellation.

For example:

```
const int NUM_TASKS = 4;

CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

Task[] tasks = new Task[NUM_TASKS];
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_TASKS; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;
        }
    }, ct);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Your button can call `cts.Cancel();` to cancel the tasks.

**Update for question update:**

There are a few ways to do what you ask.  One way is to use `ct.IsCancellationRequested` to check cancellation without throwing, then allow your task to complete.  Then `Task.WaitAll(tasks)` will complete when all of the tasks have been cancelled.

I've updated the code to reflect that change.

Comment: That will block the UI for at most 4 seconds

Comment: This is an example that will wait for all of the tasks, and each task will check for completion every second.  It's not given in the full context of a GUI app.

Comment: I agree with @Matt's answer. But I'd like to note that `var task = Task.WhenAll(tasks);` is heaps easier to manage. `WaitAll()` will throw an exception, and an ugly `AggregateException` at that - if any of the tasks faulted OR were cancelled.
Please see the defined behavior of this method on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384(v=vs.110).aspx). In the vast majority of cases, that behaviour means all you need to do is check the returned task (from `WhenAll()`) status

Comment: @Matt, Thanks for your Solution. Above code i have tried with 5 or more task it is not working. Could you please tell me i can call cts.Cancel(); before Task.WaitAll.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you should pass the same token and use this to cancel all the tasks in one go, if that's your intent.

Answer (score -3):

Use [**BackroundWorker**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class, set property **WorkerSupportsCancellation**, start tasks by calling **RunWorkerAsync()** and stop them using **CancelAsync()**

You do not neet to sync your code with the UI.

Comment: Developing a backgroundworker is not the solution. You use the CancellationTokenSource.Token in all your tasks and just cancel that source to get them all canceled.